# Open Game Center with URL scheme in iOS 10 no longer working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, game-center

Previously it worked for me to open Game Center via the following URL scheme:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter:"]];
```

In the latest iOS version this does no longer work and basically nothing happens.

How can I switch to the Game Center app in iOS 10?

EDIT: I just tried opening Game Center in the popular game Clash Royale by pressing their "Open Game Center" button and also nothing happens there. Is this a current iOS bug maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Game Center has been removed from iOS 10.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017084-DontLinkElementID_24)

Comment: How could I miss that? Thank you! But how does logging into Game Center work now? Does it have to be done In-App? I've seen that there's a settings screen for Game Center and one can login there. Is it possible to link my user to that?

Comment: Yes, there's still the underlying mechanisms there for things like identity and achievements, it's just that there's no standalone application for it now. As far as logging in is concerned, if I remember correctly, this is no different – the user gets prompted to log in via a standard prompt within your application.

Comment: Yes, there's the standard login prompt at the start, but if they tap that away....they have to go to the settings app now, which we can't directly link to without getting rejected as it seems like (at least not to the Game Center settings page).